# meaning of deploy term on Application Server

Tags: jboss7.x, application-server

Can you please explain me what is the meaning of deploy term on Application Server (JBoss for example) ? Does it mean class loading of war/ear to JVM ?
If so , does war/ear is being undeploy automatically when server is stopped ?
Does war with deployed marker is deploy also when server is stop ?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy an app, the application servers allocates the resources needed for that app to work.. Like you say, it means loading the app's classes, but also making database connections, etc.

When you stop the server, all apps are undeployed (because you are terminating the jvm). Shutting down the server releases all the resources that were allocated.

Once the app server is down, the jvm no longer exists, so no app will be deployed..

Comment: but in JBoss for example , when you start the server for the first time , war marker will change to isdeploying and then to deployed. After you stop the server and start it again marker will not go through the isdeploying stage again

Comment: are you sure about this? I believe jboss will have a dodeploy and a isdeploying file.. when startup finishes, you will have only deployed file..